# User not valid from external link

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a website that outputs Excel reports with hyperlinks back to secure content.  One of the links would look like this...

```
http://www.[site].com/externalLinkDigester?externalSession=[SHA Encrypted Text]
```

The query string argument (externalSession) is a unique alphanumeric string that is only valid for 24 hours and can only be accessed by the user who created the report.  My controller looks something like this...

```
class ExternalLinkDigester{

   def springSecurityService;

    def index = {
        def currentUser = springSecurityService?.currentUser

        if (!currentUser){
            redirect(controller:'login')
        }

        def request = ExternalSession.findByName(params.externalSession);

        if (request.isExpired(){
            //show expired content page
        }


        if (sameUser(currentUser, request.user){
            //show content
        }else{
            redirect(controller:'login')
        }



    }
}
```

**The problem** is that no matter what the `springSecurityService.currentUser` is always null when coming form an external program like Excel even when I am logged before clicking the link however, if I copy and paste the link into the browser it seems to work fine.  Help!

How can I securely access content this way?

Comment: Does it work if link is in other app such as MS Word or outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that Excel is opening up a different browser than the one you logged in with (eg. you logged in with Firefox and when clicking the link within excel, it defaults to opening the link within Internet Explorer).  The new browser will not have the session cookie for the authenticated session so "currentUser" will appear as null.

Comment: It's the same browser with a new tab.

Comment: What's your browser and version?  Normal behavior as far as I know is that all tabs are able to reuse the same session if it's a cookie.  Unless your website uses a cookie-less session mechanism whereby a special identifier string is passed around in the URL as a parameter.  But that doesn't appear to be the case based on your example since I don't see any other parameter.